# Solve for $x$ in $5^x+5 \le 6 \cdot (\sqrt{5})^x$

Tags: calculus

$5^x+5 \le 6 \cdot (\sqrt{5})^x$

I tried:

$$5^x+5 \le 6 \cdot (\sqrt{5})^x \Leftrightarrow \frac{5^x+5}{6} \le 5^{\frac{x}{2}} \Leftrightarrow \frac{5^x}{6} + \frac{5}{6} \le (5^x)^{\frac{1}{2}} \Leftrightarrow \frac{5^x}{6}-\frac{(5^x)^{\frac{1}{2}}}{1} \le -\frac{5}{6} \Leftrightarrow \frac{5^x-(5^x)^{\frac{1}{2}}\cdot 6}{6} \le -\frac{5}{6} \Leftrightarrow 5^x-(5^x)^{\frac{1}{2}}\cdot 6 \le -\frac{5}{36} \Leftrightarrow ???$$

What do I do next? Am I doing it right?

Comment: Set $(\sqrt 5)^x=y$ in the beginning and solve for $y$, instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$5^{ x }+5\le 6\cdot (\sqrt { 5 } )^{ x }\\ \sqrt { { 5 }^{ x } } =t\\ { t }^{ 2 }-6t+5\le 0\\ \left( t-1 \right) \left( t-5 \right) \le 0\\ t\in \left[ 1;5 \right] \\ 1\le \sqrt { { 5 }^{ x } } \le 5\\ 1\le { 5 }^{ x }\le 25\\ { 5 }^{ 0 }\le { 5 }^{ x }\le { 5 }^{ 2 }\\ 0\le x\le 2$$

Answer (score 2):

As commented, solve the quadratic inequality:

$$y^2+5\le 6y\iff (y-1)(y-5)\le0\iff\ldots$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $y=(\sqrt 5)^x$. The inequation becomes
$$y^2-6y+5\le0$$
which should be easy to solve.

Don't forget that $y>0$.